# On click method lounches everything at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button click function, which should operate as normal javascript function and launch all functions one by one, but it launches all at one time. Thats what Date().getTime() function shows in console. So how to make that it would be launched not all at the same time, but one by one?

```
$('#slider-menu li:last-child a').click(function(e) {
    console.log("1# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("2# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    $('#slider-menu .span12 li').removeClass("active");
    console.log("3# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    $('#slider-menu li:last-child').addClass("active");
    console.log("4# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    $('.trikampis').remove();
    console.log("5# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    var ilgis3 = $('#slider-menu .active').width() / 2;
    console.log("6# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    $(this).after("<div class='trikampis'></div>");
    console.log("7# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    $('#slider-menu .trikampis').css("border-left-width", ilgis3 + "px");
    console.log("8# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    $('#slider-menu .trikampis').css("border-right-width", ilgis3 + "px");
    console.log("9# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    $('#slider-menu ul').css("border-bottom-color", $('#slider-menu li.active a').css("background"));
    console.log("10# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    if ($('.slider-1').length !== 0) {
        $('.slider-1').addClass("slider-1-a");
        $('.slider-1').removeClass("slider-1");
        console.log("11# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    }
    if ($('.slider-2').length !== 0) {
        $('.slider-2').addClass("slider-2-a");
        $('.slider-2').removeClass("slider-2");
        console.log("11# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    }
    if ($('.slider-3-a').length !== 0) {
        $('.slider-3-a').addClass("slider-3");
        $('.slider-3-a').removeClass("slider-3-a");
        console.log("11# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    }
    $('.slider').hide();
    console.log("12# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    $("#preloader").show(); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
    console.log("13# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    $("#status").show(); // will first fade out the loading animation
    console.log("14# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    $('.slider').load('/we-have-puppies #product-slideshow');
    console.log("15# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    $.getScript('http://bisonai.infoaleja.lt/wp-content/themes/bisonai/js/slideris.js');
    console.log("16# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    $('.pagr-info-blokas h3 a').css("color", $('#slider-menu li.active a').css("background"));

    console.log("17# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

    $("#status").fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
    $("#preloader").delay(700).fadeOut("slow"); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
    $('.slider').fadeIn();
    console.log("18# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));

});
```

Comment: Are you expecting a delay between each?

Comment: It is doing it one by one but the computer is fast enough to do it in milliseconds, the ones you are cutting off of your time by doing the `Math.round`

Comment: well, I need that the part below ajax load function will launch immediatly, and then ajax script should load. Now it looks like everything launches at the same time..

Comment: The animations happen asynchronously, you think they act synchronously. That is what the finished callback is for.

Comment: @sergioadh you are right at this point. I have changed it without round and without division.

`01# 1376690981469 
02# 1376690981469 
03# 1376690981469 
04# 1376690981470
05# 1376690981470 
06# 1376690981471 
07# 1376690981472 
08# 1376690981472 
09# 1376690981472
10# 1376690981473 
11# 1376690981473 
11# 1376690981474
12# 1376690981474 
13# 1376690981474 
14# 1376690981474 
15# 1376690982015 
16# 1376690982086
17# 1376690982087 
18# 1376690982089`

Doesnt look like significant change. couse ajax call should take longer pause

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for console.time(PERIOD_NAME)

Use it like this:

```
console.time('t')
if ($('.slider-1').length !== 0) {
        $('.slider-1').addClass("slider-1-a");
        $('.slider-1').removeClass("slider-1");
        console.log("11# " + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000));}
console.timeEnd('t')
//Outputs t: 0.010ms
```

Comment: good point with console.time('t'),
I have checked and part before ajax call duration is 3.000ms, and the part from ajax call to the end is ~700ms. but everything changes in one moment..?

Comment: It's that 3ms go really fast. Try using setTimeout and use the callback